# DjangoCMS Plugin Tutorial: Poll Plugin list shows `poll object` for list of options

Tags: django-cms

I went through the [plugin tutorial](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/introduction/plugins.html), as well as the preceding few, but it seems like there's a bug while trying to add a plugin.

On a page in Structure view, I have an empty placeholder. I click +. Click on Poll Plugin, and a modal pops up with a `<select>` that seems to have been generated through xhr at this route:
`/en/admin/cms/page/add-plugin/?placeholder_id=13&plugin_type=PollPluginPublisher&plugin_language=en HTTP/1.1`
Inside of that select is `<option>`s with "Poll object" for each poll that I've created. I choose one, and press save. The object shows up as a plugin for the placeholder. The odd part is that the correct `__str__` (I use Python3, so I'm not using `__unicode__`) is being used here, which was gotten from the route `/en/ HTTP/1.1`: "Which browser do you prefer?"

Why is `/en/` giving me the correct string representation of the `PollPluginModel`, but when using the Add Plugin modal `/en/admin/cms/page/add-plugin/?...` I get the `Poll`'s string representation?

Comment: I'd suggest asking this, probably with a link here, on the IRC channel as you'll probably need one of the core devs for the appropriate answer; https://www.django-cms.org/en/support/